# Python crashes computer due to low memory

Tags: python, pyspark, out-of-memory

Please excuse in advance if this is a duplicate question - I searched stackoverflow but did not find this question asked this way.

I am running Python 2.7 on my computer and since I started working with an 8 million row data set; I have been received an error message that my computer is low on memory. I get this message the moment I upload the dataset _ I don't even start processing it.

It actually crashed my whole computer several times. Since this is my work computer I asked IT to clean my virtual memory, increase whatever memory they can and even clean my HD. But as expected I am still hitting that issue. In a personal setting, I used python jupyter notebook on AWS to overcome this issue - but I don't have this option at work.

What would you recommend? Is pyspark the best way to go? I am new to spark, is there something similar to jupyter notebook for spark?

Thank you very much

Comment: you could start downsampling your dataset, picking a random subset of rows

Comment: Or you could process your data in chunks, remove unneeded columns from every row, etc.  Without knowing the specifics, there could be a lot of solutions to this problem without finding a new tool.

Comment: I unfortunately can't downsample the data - the requirement is for actuals - the 8 million rows are already a chunk - I have multiple datasets like that that I would like to merge; I am trying to establish a customer journey and for that I need all of the customer history - every transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: Either read in chunks, or try `mmap`.

This is mostly independent of python, since you seem to try to load more data into your main memory than you actually have RAM. Your operating system will try to compensate by putting excess and/or unneeded data onto your hard disk/ssd [which is slow like hell - a single CPU Skylake system can reach over 30GB/s, a fast NVMe SSD maybe 2GB/s, and your normal HDD is in the 0.1GB/s range]. Windows calls this virtual memory, on Linux it's swap and on Mac I don't know.

The usual solution is to process the data in chunks.

Let's assume you have a huuuge text file with millions of lines, then you could process one line at a time. Some perlish pseudo-code:

```
$FH = open ("myhugefile");
while ($line = getLine ($FH)) {
     process ($line);
}
close $FH;
```

What you try to do seems to be more like this:

```
$FH = open ("myhugefile");
$array = new Array ();
while ($line = getLine ($FH)) {
    push ($array, $line);
}
close $FH;   
foreach ($line in $array) {
    process ($line);
}
```

Since the `$array` is stored in memory, the second approach will have some problems with huge datasets.

If course your `process()`-function might produce lot's of data, too. So it might be necessary to write that out to the HDD/SSD instead of storing it in memory.

In the compiler construction lecture I attended another student used `mmap` to read the files into his parser. This proved to be **very** fast compared to what others did for that first assignment (however, others did catch up for later assignments, since his actual processing was slower due to bad/naive implementation).

Anyway, the basic idea behind `mmap` is to let your operating system map your file into your memory. It will then dynamically load the content for you, while you can access it like your normal memory objects.

Generic explanation can be found on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap

Python2 docs with examples: https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html
(Seems pretty easy)

Comment: Thank You - this is very helpful; I will try it all

Comment: You're welcome. For further research: You could also try to look at DBMS building. That is, how to produce a processing pipeline from a SQL statement that is (a) very fast and (b) can handle huge amounts of data. Those guys have many nice tricks (but some are rather complicated and probably overkill). Big data, e.g. hadoop and other map-reduce implementations face similar challenges. Maybe you could use something like that?

Comment: I do have an hadoop infrasturcture that I can use - probably with Spark; but I wanted to understand if there aren't ways in python - I will definitely try the chunk and mmap approach. I think eventually I will need to move to Spark, just because the datasets are growing every year. THANK YOU